# Replace a specified string within a string which matches the regex pattern c#

Tags: c#, regex, replace, pattern-matching, regex-group

I have a multiline text box which contains below string URLs:

```
http://foodfacts.ambigouos.com
http://articles.ambigouos.com
http://www.dirtshirt.org
```

I want to replace/update a string `http to https` from the above URLs which has `ambigouos.com` as a domain with Regex.

**Expected output:**

```
https://foodfacts.ambigouos.com
https://articles.ambigouos.com
http://www.dirtshirt.org
```

**Below code tried but not working:**

```
multilinebox.text = Regex.Replace(multilinebox.text, @"^http?://[a-zA-Z]*(\.ambigouos\.com)$", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Below code tried but not working` How **specifically** is it not working?

Comment: Can you define `not working`?

Comment: You're aware that your regex matches `http://` or `htt://`, right?

Comment: you might not need regexp, just check if line `.Contains("ambigouos.com")` and then do `.Replace("http://", "https://")`

Comment: @trailmax That is true if only OP does not want to make sure only an HTTP link is changed.

Comment: In your current code you are using the Replace overload: public static string Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement, RegexOptions options);. So you are not replacing with "https" but with "$1" (string literal)

Comment: Why there's `https://www.dirtshirt.org` in the expected output since it doesn't have the domain `ambigouos.com` or a subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may leverage the fact that the strings are at the start of a *line* (i.e. you should compile the regex with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` flag), you do not need to check the end of the string/line here. Also, you need to set the grouping construct around the whole non-fixed part of the string.

**If you need to only handle matches at the start of a line** use

```
Regex.Replace(multilinebox.text, @"^http://((?:[^/]*\.)?ambigouos\.com)", "https://$1", 
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

**If you want to handle matches *anywhere* inside a string** remove `^` and `| RegexOptions.Multiline` use

```
Regex.Replace(multilinebox.text, 
          @"http://((?:[^/]*\.)?ambigouos\.com)", 
          "https://$1", 
          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ehttp%3a%2f%2f%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%2f%5d*%5c.%29%3fambigouos%5c.com%29&i=http%3a%2f%2ffoodfacts.ambigouos.com%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2farticles.ambigouos.com%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fambigouos.com%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fwww.dirtshirt.org&r=https%3a%2f%2f%241&o=m).

**Detasils**

- `^` - start of a line (since `RegexOptions.Multiline` is used)
- `http://` - a literal substring
- `((?:[^/]*\.)?ambigouos\.com)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `(?:[^/]*\.)?` - an optional sequence of any 0+ chars other than `/`, and then a `.`
  - `ambigouos\.com` - a literal substring.

You may add `\r\n` to the negated character class to avoid overflowing across lines, i.e. `[^/]` => `[^/\r\n]`.

Comment: `http://foodfacts.ambigouos.com/` is not matching with the above regex hence not replacing to `https://foodfacts.ambigouos.com/` suggest!!

Comment: @PPB [It does, look here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ehttp%3a%2f%2f%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%2f%5d*%5c.%29%3fambigouos%5c.com%29&i=http%3a%2f%2ffoodfacts.ambigouos.com%2f&r=https%3a%2f%2f%241&o=m). Here is [a C# demo](https://ideone.com/NpqHLb).

Comment: @PPB Do you mean to say you do not need to match these URLs at the start of a line but anywhere inside the string?

Comment: @PPB But that means you want to match `http://` at the start of a line. There is no need removing `^` start-of-line anchor. Have you added the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option? Show the exact code you have at IDEONE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166454/discussion-between-ppb-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: This is working with `http://foodfacts.ambigouos.com` but not working with 
`<a href="http://fitness.ambigouos.com/">link for fitness</a>` Kindly suggest!!

Comment: @PPB Come on,  if you want to match the links at the start of the line, use `^`, else, remove it.